# How do I remove a substring/character from a string in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, filter, substring

I am writing a program in which I need to filter a string. So I have a map of characters, and I want the string to filter out all characters that are not in the map. Is there a way for me to do this?

Let's say we have the string and map:

```
str = "ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD"

Map('A' -> "A", 'D' -> "D")
```

Then I want the string to be filtered down to:

```
str = "BCBCBCBCBC"
```

Also, if I find a given substring in the string, is there a way I can replace that with a different substring?

So for example, if we have the string:

```
"The number ten is even"
```

Could we replace that with:

```
"The number 10 is even"
```

Comment: What if you had `Map('A' -> "B", 'C' -> "D")` or maybe even `Map('A' -> "W", 'X' -> "D")`? How then should `str` be filtered?

Comment: If you only need to have a **Set** of characters, maybe you should use a `Set` instead of a `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

**To filter the String with the map is just a filter command:**

```
val str = "ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD"
val m = Map('A' -> "A", 'D' -> "D")

str.filterNot(elem => m.contains(elem))
```

A more functional alternative as recommended in comments

```
str.filterNot(m.contains)
```

**Output**

```
scala> str.filterNot(elem => m.contains(elem))
res3: String = BCBCBCBCBC
```

**To replace elements in the String:**

```
string.replace("ten", "10")
```

**Output**

```
scala> val s  = "The number ten is even"
s: String = The number ten is even

scala> s.replace("ten", "10")
res4: String = The number 10 is even
```

Comment: Glad to help, please, accept the answer so anyone with the same question can reach to it quickly

Comment: This can be simplified to `str.filterNot(m.contains)` which is a more functional way of doing it, but perhaps more confusing for a beginner.